# Primality is not existential over true arithmetic

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\Phi=\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{N},+,*,0,1)$ be the theory of true arithmetic and
$$\operatorname{prime}(x):=x\neq1\land\forall z(\exists k(x=k*z) \rightarrow (z=1\lor z=x))$$
be a formula for primality. How can I show that $\operatorname{prime}(x)$ is not equivalent to an existential formula modulo $\Phi$? It seems like I have to find two nonstandard models $\mathcal{N}\subset\mathcal{M}$ of $\Phi$ and $n\in N$, which is prime in $\mathcal{N}$ but not in $\mathcal{M}$.

**Edit**: The motivation for this question came from looking for examples of complete theories that are not model complete. I know that model completeness is equivalent to every formula being equivalent to an existential formula and I wanted to show that this fails for some specific 'interesting' formula.

But as my example doesnt work due to the MRDP Theorem, apparently the problem boils down to finding some formula $\varphi(x)$ which defines some non recursively enumerable set, right?

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to the universal formula $\forall z\forall k:(kz=x\, \to\, z=1\lor z=x) \land(x\ne1)$?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. But what about the existential case.

Comment: Thinking out loud - because primality is a computable property, the set of primes is a Diophantine set.  As such, it should be definable by a purely existential formula.  I suppose that somehow that formula could fail to be provably equivalent to the formula above, but I'm not sure how.  Could you give the source of this problem?

Comment: @CarlMummert: If the existential formula _happens to_ be equivalent to primality, then by definition this equivalence is a fact of true arithmetic, I'd say ...

Comment: @Henning Makholm: indeed, and the equivalence would be provable in PA even. Maybe I have misread the problem?

Comment: @CarlMummert: If so, we're both misreading it.

Comment: Are you allowing bounded quantifiers?  Like would $\exists k . \forall j < k : P(j, k)$ be a counterexample to your claim?  It sounds like no, which might be the source of the confusion.

Comment: @Achilles: I wanted to ping you to bring your attention back to this question, given the answer - is there any clarification you can give?

Comment: @CarlMummert I have edited in my motivation for the question.

Comment: @Achilles: thanks, that makes sense. I wrote something that I think answers that question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think what you want to prove is true.

[Matiyasevich's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich's_theorem) states that every recursively enumerable set can be defined by an existential formula over $(\mathbb N,0,1,{+},{\times})$ -- and the set of primes is certainly recursively enumerable.

Comment: Not only this, but we in fact have explicit existential formulas defining the primes. For example, see pg. 331 of the survey paper [MR0432534 (55 #5522)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=432534) 
Davis, Martin; Matijasevič, Yuri; Robinson, Julia. *Hilbert's tenth problem: Diophantine equations: positive aspects of a negative solution*. In **[Mathematical developments arising from Hilbert problems (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Vol. XXVIII, Northern Illinois Univ., De Kalb, Ill., 1974)](https://bookstore.ams.org/pspum-28)**, pp. 323–378. Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R. I., 1976.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find formulas that are not equivalent to existential formulas, you can do this using [Post's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem), which says in particular that there are $m$-complete sets at each level $\Pi^0_n$ and $\Sigma^0_n$ of the arithmetical hierarchy, and so in particular the arithmetical hierarchy does not collapse.

A particular example of a $\Pi^0_1$ complete set is the complement of the halting problem. This set is cannot be definable by an existential formula because then the halting problem would be both r.e. and co-r.e., and so it would be computable.  Thus the formula that defines the complement of the halting problem cannot be equivalent to an existential formula.   There are examples at higher levels of the arithmetical hierarchy as well.